# Powershell script that finds password expiration by a specific date with output to csv

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords

**NOTE I AM A NEWBIE TO POWERSHELL**

Ok I am needing to get the expired passwords for multiple users whose passwords expire by a specific date. I am needing the user names and emails of the users. I am not getting the right output. I keeping getting a message that says InputObject. I'm not sure what to add here and I know I am missing something.

See Below:

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Students,DC=domain,DC=domain,DC=com"  -properties PasswordNeverExpires,msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | where {$_.enabled -eq $true -and $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq  $False} | select Name,@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={([datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")).DateTime}} | where {($_.ExpiryDate | get-date)  -gt (get-date) -and ($_.ExpiryDate | get-date) -eq (get-date).adddays(20)  Export-csv C:\Temp\Password }
```

Comment: Please update your question and use code formatting (indent 4 spaces) for your code sample.

Comment: There are lots of examples of this all over the web. No reason for you to do this from scratch.   [powershell 'csv password expiration by date'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+%27csv+password+expiration+by+date%27&form=ANNTH1&refig=d01fcb41d1fb45ffbcdf4e13b4153d70&sp=-1&pq=powershell+%27csv+password+expiration+by+da%27&sc=0-42&qs=n&sk=&cvid=d01fcb41d1fb45ffbcdf4e13b4153d70). Being new is fine, but [Windows Server ADAC](https://www.petri.com/use-active-directory-administrative-center-create-powershell-commands), will write baseline PowerShell code for you to tweak as needed

Comment: Yes I found a few but I need it to be more specific. I need to add 20 days, I need to find users accounts who will be expiring on 9/2/2020 and I need their name and email address along with the expiry date to output in a csv file. This is where I am getting stuck

Comment: Then that is just using the Get-Date cmdlet and specifying the date +/-.    Example: Get-Date # Results Thursday, 13 August, 2020 14:12:36
(Get-Date).AddDays(-3) # Results Monday, 10 August, 2020 14:12:50 and you are not asking for email address in your code. As well as a few other errors in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web search I linked to would have given you these articles...

> [Get-ADUser: Getting Active Directory Users Info via PowerShell](http://woshub.com/get-aduser-getting-active-directory-users-data-via-powershell/#:%7E:text=User%20email%20address%20is%20one%20of%20the%20user,%2A%20-properties%20EmailAddress%20-SearchBase%20%27OU%3DParis%2COU-Fr%2CDC%3Dwoshub%2CDC%3Dcom%27%7C%20select-object%20Name%2C%20EmailAddress)
>
> [Powershell – Get AD Users Password Expiry Date](https://morgantechspace.com/2015/03/powershell-get-ad-users-password-expiry-date.html)

You could have also use the Windows Server ADAC to write the baseline code for you via a GUI click-thru, that you could tweak as needed.

> [Use AD Administrative Center to Create PowerShell Commands](https://www.petri.com/use-active-directory-administrative-center-create-powershell-commands)

... and the help files, would give you all you need to construct this properly

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-ADUser).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-ADUser).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-ADUser -Examples
# Results
<#
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Finance,OU=UserAccounts,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM"
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "*SvcAccount"' | FT Name,SamAccountName -A
Get-ADUser GlenJohn -Properties *
Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq "GlenJohn"} -SearchBase "DC=AppNC" -Properties mail -Server lds.Fabrikam.com:50000
#>
Get-help -Name Get-ADUser -Full
Get-help -Name Get-ADUser -Online
```

I modified the code a bit from the article, as spaces in propertyNames,
variables, fields, filenames, etc., are just an unneeded pain to deal with.

```
<#
Get Password Expiry Date of all Enabled AD Users

The following powershell script find all the enabled Active Directory users 
whose PasswordNeverExpires flag value is equal to False and list the attribute 
value samAccountName and Password Expire Date. The Active Directory computed 
attribute msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed is timeStamp attribute and its 
value will be stored as integer, so we are using expression to convert timestamp 
value into normal date time.
#>
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} –Properties 'SamAccountName',
'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed' |
Select-Object -Property 'SamAccountName', 
@{
    Name       = 'PasswordExpiryDate'
    Expression = {[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}
} | 
Where-Object -Property 'PasswordExpiryDate' -LE (Get-Date).AddDays(20) | 
Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\PasswordExpiryReport.Csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

<#
You can add any extra attributes that are supported/available in Active Directory property listing.

If you want to add the attributes mail and pwdLastset with this script, you can 
simply add these attributes as comma separated values.
#>

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} –Properties 'SamAccountName', 
'mail',
'pwdLastSet',
'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed' |
Select-Object -Property 'SamAccountName', 'Name', 'DisplayName', 'mail',
@{
    Name       = 'PasswordLastSet'
    Expression = {[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."pwdLastSet")}
}, 
@{
    Name       = 'PasswordExpiryDate'
    Expression = {[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}
} | 
Where-Object -Property 'PasswordExpiryDate' -LE (Get-Date).AddDays(20) | 
Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\PasswordExpiryReport.Csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Oh wow this is exactly it! I definitely have a lot of learning to do with ADAC and powershell. Thank you all for your assistance!

Comment: No worries. Glad it will help you move forward. Also of note. If this resolved your use case, be sure to mark it as your accepted answer for the benefit of others who come here and potentially have the same needs. take care/stay safe.