# How to validate an expired password using powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to create a PowerShell script to let user change their expired password in AD, but the problem is that I can't verify the password once it is expired. I could do a reset, but I don't want reset the password if the user cannot input their correct password.

For example, if I have a TestUser with Password 123456

```
(new-object directoryservices.directoryentry "","TestUser", "1234")
format-default : The following exception occurred while retrieving member "distinguishedName": "The directory service is unavailable."
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], ExtendedTypeSystemException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand

(new-object directoryservices.directoryentry "","TestUser", "123456")
format-default : The following exception occurred while retrieving member "distinguishedName": "The directory service is unavailable."
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], ExtendedTypeSystemException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

I have also tried using:
`Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" /c -Credential (Get-Credential)`

Both yield `Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The user name or password is incorrect.`.

Any idea how to check a valid password even if it is expired?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Apparently you doing this from another account (otherwise: how did you logon with an expired account?) in which case you might look to the `PasswordNeverExpires` property, see e.g.: [finds password expiration by a specific date with output to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63398417/1701026)

Comment: Btw: "*I am trying to create a PowerShell script to let user change their expired password in AD*", by doing that (letting the user enter his password in a custom interfase under another account) you probbly creating a security breach, it is better to just tell the user to change his password by pressing `cntrl-alt-del` --> `change password`

Comment: @iRon Unfortunately, for most users, Ctrl-Alt-Del (or Command-Alt-Delete) means force close, and they won't get any "change password" option. Not every user are using Windows. Most users are using Mac, and some are even androids. So I have to create a script that will be executed by web interface. I plan to use python or nodejs or php to execute the script.

Comment: @iRon I know about system security, and I know how to harden system, and I can do it myself. I just need to check whether the password entered by the user correct or not. If our userbase are Windows based, I won't be asking this workaround.

Comment: Does this help? [Web interface to allow users to change their Active Directory password](https://serverfault.com/q/37169/536173)

Comment: @stackprotector Yes and no.. There is PassCore that I can use, but I really don't want to install IIX if I can at AD server. I will try to use its C# and adapt to PowerShell. Let see if I can make something out of it.